# How do I use dynamic keyword in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm using Azure Resource Graph which is using Kusto language for query Azure resources and confused how I can create my own objects via `dynamic` keyword from existing ones. Example is below which is showing that I'm trying to just assign the same value to `disk` to dynamic object `osDisk` but it fails with `InvalidQuery`. What am I doing wrong?

```
where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines' 
| extend disk = properties.storageProfile.osDisk 
| extend osDisk = dynamic({"osdisk" : properties.storageProfile.osDisk})
|project disk, osDisk
```

Error

```
Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2019-07-20T01:55:46.6283092Z, correlationId = 297ad2ed-81f2-49b3-86b2-5f38e2394923. (Code: BadRequest) Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code: InvalidQuery)
```

Removing `dynamic` line option returns results properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `pack()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/packfunction

```
print disk = "disk_value", properties = dynamic({"storageProfile":{"osDisk":"osDisk_value"}})
| project disk,  osDisk = pack("osDisk", properties.storageProfile.osDisk)
```